# how to fix "-bash: pod: command not found" error

Tags: cocoapods

I want to install pod file from [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating) but not able to install.
Terminal showing "-bash: pod: command not found" error.
Any suggestions, how to fix this issue?

System info:- El captain 10.11.6 Xcode Version:- 8.2.1 
[image]

Comment: From the instructions page: "Before you begin:

Install Xcode 7
[**Install CocoaPods (strongly recommended)**](https://developers.google.com/ios/guides/cocoapods)"

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
sudo gem install cocoapods

Comment: Hello Tincat! You can post this answer even as a comment! Suggestions aren't always expected to be an answer :)