# zsh: command not found: pod

Tags: cocoapods

Can someone help me with this:

> zsh: command not found: pod

I bought a new Mac and I copied my Xcode project to my new Mac. When I try to install pods, this is the message in terminal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to fix "-bash: pod: command not found" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44528879/how-to-fix-bash-pod-command-not-found-error)

Comment: Thank you but this not fix my problem, I tired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try below command on your terminal
`brew install cocoapods`

For more details refer another post [pod install -bash: pod: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14202255/pod-install-bash-pod-command-not-found)